# Discord.py: `on_member_update()` called repeatedly [1 guild only]

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want my bot to change user roles depending on nickname patterns (basically the company ID).
When the user puts his ID in the nickname, `on_member_update()` is called normally.
In the function, the bot adds roles and changes the nickname again to a specific pattern. This triggers the `on_member_update()` yet again.
*Note that I have the bot in 1 guild only.*

I tried to stop it by adding

```py
if before.display_name == after.display_name:
  return
```

But it still enters the function when the nickname is changed. Is there a way to avoid the function triggering itself again?

The code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.display_name == after.display_name:
        return
    id = re.findall(r'\d{6,7}', after.display_name)
    if not id:
        return
    else:
        # Business logic (changing nickname, adding roles etc...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an entire answer but it will guide you in the right direction.

You have to keep record of ids of changed users either in a database or using a JSON file. I called it `users_changed` which should be a list.

**Note:** that `id` is reserved in Python you must use another thing maybe even `id_`

```py
users_changed = [11111,22222,33333] # get this from the db or file.

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.id in users_changed:
        return

    # code here
    # then add before.id into the users_changed
```

Comment: This kinda helps. Thank you Abdulaziz bro.
I guess it's a bad idea to change a nickname inside `on_member_update()` but I don't see other options for now.

Comment: Actually there is a better method, make a task and run like every 15 minutes. Inside of it loop over all members and do your thing.